# Update data fetched by asyncData() in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

I wonder if there is a way to update the data returned by `asyncData()`? For a forum app, in the post page, I got the replies data in the following way:

```
async asyncData(){
    const {data:replies}=await axios.get('replies.json')
    return { replies }
}
```

And render it in the template:

```
<div v-for="rep in replies">
    <div>{{rep.likes}}</div>
    <div>{{rep.content}}</div>
</div>
```

I want to implement a `replyToPost` feature in the post page. However, when a user posts a reply, I don't know how to update the `replies` data that already fetched by the `asyncData()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any asyncData item, in your case 'replies' behaves just like a regular data item once it is initialised because [Nuxt.js will automatically merge the returned object with the component data.](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data).  Therefore you can alter it as you would any other data item. I assume 'replies' is an array so you could just have a method:

```
newReply(reply) {
  this.replies.push(reply)
}
```

and it will be added to the array.

Comment: In which hook do I have to put this method?

Comment: do I have to call this method in asyncData()?

Comment: It doesn't go in any of the lifecycle hooks. Simply put the method in your methods object in the component instance.